# Drawing (a) number

Tags: sentence-meaning, numbers

1. Draw an 8.
2. Draw 8.

What does each imply, and what are the differences between the two?

Comment: The title, "The number/number/a number" what does it mean?

Comment: It is unrelated to your question, but I will point out that it should be "Draw **an** 8", rather than "draw **a** 8". Since *8* starts with a vowel sound "ay".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that one would not say #2. . .

unless it was already understood that it was some kind of card game in which one might draw eight *cards*.  How many cards do I draw? Draw eight.  Or, perhaps in kindergarten:  How many squares did you want me to draw? Draw eight.

Your sentence #1 asks the hearer to draw a "figure-eight"; i.e., the numeral "8".

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian. Then, can you explain why, when talking about numbers on a calculator, would you say, "press 8" instead of "press an 8" or even, "press the 8"?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe just because it's shorter to say and there's no chance of confusion.

Comment: Thank you again. If it is the matter of confusion, let's just assume now that that's what it is, why a frige at home, which usually holds one frige, is called with "the" all the time? Put it in the frige. Would it be confusing if I say, "put it in frige"?

Comment: It wouldn't be confusing, but it wouldn't be correct.  That's exactly the kind of situation when you would expect to use "the": to refer to _the only one there_.  (By the way, we spell it _fridge_, rather than "frige", even though there is no D in _refrigerator_.)